# How to retrieve linkedin profiles via api for accented urls?

Tags: perl, linkedin-api

I'm trying to get info from LinkedIn API, but i run into some issues when the urls have any kind of accented characters.

For non-accented urls the call to the API works fine and i can retrieve data without problems, but when i try with accented urls i get an error.

I have tried escaping the url but it doesn't work:

uri_escape_utf8:

```
'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=' . uri_escape_utf8('xxxxx');
```

uri_escape:

```
'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=' . uri_escape('xxxxx');
```

no escaping:

```
'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=xxxxx';
```

double escape:

```
uri_escape_utf8('https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/url=' . uri_escape_utf8('xxxxx'));
```

Comment: What does the manual say?

Comment: Generally speaking, should be the first. The problem could be with your `xxxxx`. Pleaes provide a dump the $url produced by the first snippet using the following: `{ use Data::Dumper; local $Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1; warn(Dumper($url)); }`

Comment: `uri_escape_utf8('xxxxx')` is equal to `'xxxxx'`. Where does the string that you're passing to `uri_escape_utf8` come from? Is it a string literal in your code or have you read it from an external source? `uri_escape_utf8` won't work unless you have *decoded* any encoded strings, and if you are using string literals that means adding `use utf8` at the top of your program

Comment: The url comes from the linkedin page: https://www.linkedin.com/in/anaïs-thévoz-b070838 for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Update

I'm pretty sure the problem will be that you don't have `use utf8` at the top of your program. This code correctly encodes the i-diaresis as `%C3%AF` and the e-acute as `%C3%A9`

```
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use URI::Escape qw/ uri_escape_utf8 /;

say uri_escape_utf8('http://linkedin.com/in/anaïs-thévoz-b070838');
```

#### output

```
http%3A%2F%2Flinkedin.com%2Fin%2Fana%C3%AFs-th%C3%A9voz-b070838
```

Whereas without the `use utf8`, Perl is seeing the UTF-8-encoded bytes instead of characters, like this

```
"http://linkedin.com/in/ana\xC3\xAFs-th\xC3\xA9voz-b070838"
```

and `uri_escape_utf8` double-encodes `"\xC3\xAF"` as `%C3%83%C2%AF` and `"\xC3\xA9"` as `%C3%83%C2%A9` like this

#### output

```
http%3A%2F%2Flinkedin.com%2Fin%2Fana%C3%83%C2%AFs-th%C3%83%C2%A9voz-b070838
```

so the LinkedIn server gets confused

---

URLs use only eight-bit octets and there is no assumed encoding for Unicode characters

[RFC 3986](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3986.txt) is the current standard for Uniform Resource Identifiers (URIs), and Section 2 -- Characters -- explains that the only characters allowed in a URL are the special delimiters `!`, `#`, `$`, `&`, `'`, `(`, `)`, `*`, `+`, `,`, `/`, `:`, `;`, `=`, `?`, `@`, `[`, `]` in addition to the unreserved characters that can be used to build identifiers which match the regex pattern `[0-9A-Za-z._~-]`

You can extend this restriction by using the percent sign `%` followed by two hex digits to represent any octet without its special meaning, but this doesn't cover multi-byte characters, and there is no implied encoding if they are used within a URL.

If you are using [`URI::Escape`](https://metacpan.org/pod/URI::Escape) then `uri_escape_utf8` will correctly encode any string in UTF-8 as a combination of unreserved and percent-encoded characters, but the server must be expecting a utf-8-encoded URL

The most likely problems are

- Your original string is already encoded and contains encoded bytes instead of characters, so `uri_escape_utf8` is encoding an encoded string
- The *LinkedIn* API doesn't expect UTF-8-encoded URLs

Comment: Already tried encoding only the domain part leaving the other part without encoding like:

" uri_escape_utf8('https://www.linkedin.com/') . 'rest/of/the/url' "

Comment: good catch, i wasn't using use utf8! unfortunately linkedin API doesn't understand this url either. I'm starting to think that is the linkedin API itself that has the problem.